# yum remove cmake failed

Tags: cmake, centos, yum

I want to update cmake,the old version is 2.8.But when is uninstall the old version cmake it doesn't work.

```
[chaos@localhost ~]$ cmake --version
cmake version 2.8.10.2
[lichao@localhost ~]$ yum info cmake
Available Packages
Name        : cmake
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.8.12.2
Release     : 2.el7
Size        : 7.1 M
Repo        : base
Summary     : Cross-platform make system
URL         : http://www.cmake.org
License     : BSD and MIT and zlib
Description : CMake is used to control the software compilation process using simple
            : platform and compiler independent configuration files. CMake generates
            : native makefiles and workspaces that can be used in the compiler
            : environment of your choice. CMake is quite sophisticated: it is possible
            : to support complex environments requiring system configuration, preprocessor
            : generation, code generation, and template instantiation.
[chaos@localhost ~]$ sudo yum remove cmake -y
[sudo] password for lichao: 
No Match for argument: cmake
No Packages marked for removal
```

Answer (score 1):

the `cmake` you use was installed manually, not using `yum`.

`yum info` shows you the information of the package that is available in your repositories (base), it is not installed, otherwise it would say

```
Repo : installed
```

so since cmake is not installed using `yum`, you cannot remove it using `yum`.

NOTE: you can also see that the version numbers differ...

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am sure I should have cmake installed because when I type                                                                                                                                     `[chaos@localhost ~]$ cmake --version 
                  cmake version 2.8.10.2  `

Comment: yes, `cmake` is installed, but probably someone compiled cmake himself and ran `make install`. Nobody ran `yum install cmake`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update it's not required to remove the package before. You can directly execute update command:

```
yum update cmake
```